# Процесс хуков функций C++

Tags: c++, ram

По мере изучения хуков C++, у меня произошел некий диссонанс с механикой этих самых хуков. Хотя у меня и есть чувство что это очень глупый вопрос, однако...

Ниже необходимый код перехвата функции CreateFileA.

---

```cpp
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct jump_near {
    BYTE opcode;
    DWORD relativeAddress;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int main() {
    HMODULE hMod = GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll");
    if(!hMod) return 1;

    jump_near* lpFunc = reinterpret_cast<jump_near*>(GetProcAddress(hMod, "CreateFileA"));

    DWORD dwProtect = PAGE_READWRITE;
    VirtualProtect(lpFunc, sizeof(jump_near), dwProtect, &dwProtect);

    lpFunc->opcode = 0xE9;
    lpFunc->relativeAddress = _CalculateDispacement(lpFunc, &_My_CreateFileA);

    VirtualProtect(lpFunc, sizeof(jump_near), dwProtect, &dwProtect);

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA("C:\\test.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Некоторые уточнения по функциям, чтобы не вставлять полный код в целях чистоты.
*
*CalculateDispacement - вычисляет относительный адрес посредством secondAddress - (firstAddress+5)

*_My_CreateFileA - выполняет MessageBox*

---

В основном, в статьях и т.п. про хуки функций находится преимущественно код и объяснение типа "Во время хука происходит прыжок на адрес функции с нашей логикой", это я в общем-то понимаю.

1. Но когда именно происходит этот прыжок, в какой момент?
2. Как я читал "#pragma pack(push,1) 'some code here' #pragma pack(pop)" производит некое выравнивание структур, тоже непонятное для меня действие.
3. Почему производится каст `lpFunc` в `jump_near*`?

---

Я находил ответы на некоторые свои вопросы, но они были неполными. На MSDN достаточно абстрактные определения и объяснения, поэтому ищу помощи тут.

Comment: pack(1) заставляет компилятор выравнивать поля на границу байта, а не на их естественную границу (для DWORD, как я понимаю это 4 байта (два младшие бита адреса равны 0)). Т.е. в структуре `*jump_near`, которая используется внутри VirtualProtect, а также заполняется GetProcAddress между полями opcode и relativeAddress не должно быть промежутка. pack push запоминает текущее состояние атрибута упаковки, pack pop  восстанавливает его. Каст нужен, поскольку GetProcAddress возвращает результат типа FARPROC (указатель другого типа), а не `jump_near*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#pragma pack` убирает отступы (padding) между полями внутри структуры. Без него размер структуры был бы `8`, а не `5` - три неиспользованных байта между `opcode` и `relativeAddress`.

Компилятор старается ставить целочисленные переменные на адреса, кратные их размеру. На каких-то архитектурах это жесткое требование, а на каких-то нарушение только замедляет доступ к переменным. x86 (которые стоят в обычных ПК) относятся к последним.

---

> Почему производится каст `lpFunc` в `jump_near*`?

По адресу функции лежат некоторые процессорные инструкции.

Чтобы ее хукнуть, надо заменить их на свои. Не обязательно копировать по этому адресу всю свою функцию, если можно просто воткнуть туда команду *"продолжить выполнение с такого-то адреса"*. Видмио `E9` - она и есть, а сразу за ней (поэтому `pragma pack`) должен идти относительный адрес.

---

> когда именно происходит этот прыжок, в какой момент?

Когда вызываются ваши свежевставленные инструкции, т.е. когда кто-то вызывает хукнутую функцию, что заставляет выполнение перейти на адрес, куда вы их записали.

Comment: Интересно, если `E9` это jmp, заменяющий инструкции в начале функции, то почему после выполнения хука (это ведь функция, завершающаяся return-ом) выполняется не только код хукнутой функции, но и остаток кода этой, которая вызывает хукнутую?

Comment: @avp Автор же не показал код своей функции, видимо туда как-то скопирован оригинал.